# how to make $translate.instant interpolation instead of concatenation

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am using translate.instant and making a string concatenation like that

```
var variable = this.$translate.instant('project.discount') + " % " + this.$translate.instant('project.applied_to') + " " +this.office;
```

how can I do that inside one $translate.instant as string interpolation instead of concatenation

Thanks,

Comment: Concatenation working fine and there is no problem with it but want to do it with interpolation just to make it more elegant that's all

Answer (score 5):

I think what you want is

```
var variable = this.$translate.instant('project.discountAndAppliedTo', {office: this.office});
```

Assuming

```
{
  "project.discountAndAppliedTo": "discount % applied to {{office}}"
}
```

Or something like that, with the key point being your interpolation variable name in {{}} in the translated value.